# How to show customer's balance by using multiple sheets pivot table?

Tags: excel

I'm using an excel table where in one sheet I record the invoices and in the other one I record the account receivables. i want to consolidate these two sheets and get the customer's balance, ex:

-Sheet one (Invoice)

`01/06/2016  Jason Gordon $ 200
02/06/2016  Jack Sparrow $ 100 
03/06/2016  Jason Gordon $ 500`

-Sheet two (Account receivable)

`01/06/2016  Jason Gordon $ 50
02/06/2016  Jack Sparrow $ 100 
10/06/2016  Jason Gordon $ 200`

-Pivot table (what I need)

Jason Gordon (Filtered Customer)

`Date        Invoice    Paid    Balance
01/06/2016   $ 200     $ 50    $ 150
03/06/2016   $ 500             $ 650
10/06/2016             $ 200   $ 450
Total        $ 700     $ 250   $ 450`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use Power Query to append the data on the two sheets. Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into 2016 as "Get and Transform". It can be used to retrieve, clean and combine data from different sources into a single data source suitable for pivot tables.